# Python - How to read different json files but to keep same list running

Tags: python, json, for-loop

This might be a tough question and I will do my best to explain the best I can!

Im trying to create a script where I run different json files through a forloop (Each of these json files has their own "data") - What I want to do is that I want to be able to add those values into a list where I later match the first object in the json and matches if it is found in the script. If it is found with the same Name then we gonna check if its last object is higher or lower than it was previous in that object name. If it is higher then we print that it has been higher and we change the value object to the new one (Which we change inside a list).

Also another thing that I want it to do is that It should only append to the list once and not n times depending on how many json files I use.

I start by showing of the json that I use which we can see it contains same Name but different number.

```
    {
        "name": "Albert",
        "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/....jpg",
        "number": "5"
    }
-----------------------------------
    {
        "name": "Albert",
        "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/....jpg",
        "number": "6"
    }
```

Ok before I continue to explain. Here is the code I wrote so I can explain it better...

```
webhook_list = [
    'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5133124/slack',
    'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5124124/slack',
    'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/5112412/slack'] #Discord different API_key/Webhook



def get_identifier(thread):

    thread_id = thread['name'] #Grab name from Json

    try:
        thread_image = thread['image'] #Grab Image from Json
    except KeyError:
        thread_image = None

    try:
        thread_number = thread['numbers'] #Grab Image from Json

    except KeyError:
        thread_number = None

    identifier = ('{}%{}%{}').format(thread_id, thread_image, thread_number) #Make them all into one "String"

    return identifier   


def script():

        old_list = [] #Old_list where we gonna append if new items arrives.
        while True:
            for thread in [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')]: #We check all names in txt file (This can be changed to however you want to print, could be a list aswell. Doesn't matter
                get_value_identifier = get_identifier(thread) #We send the value thread to get_identifier to grab the values which return of the identifier

                if get_identifier(thread) not in old_list: #if this value is not in the old list then we go in here



                    #Slack/Discord function
                    directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
                    for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
                        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
                        if filename.endswith(".json"):
                            with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
                                data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())

                                data_list = []

                                # *****************---Picture---*****************
                                try:

                                    data["attachments"][0]["thumb_url"] = information ['image_url'] #We add everything to data so we can later on be able to print it out to discord/slack

                                except Exception:
                                    data["attachments"][0][
                                        "thumb_url"] = 'https://cdn.browshot.com/static/images/not-found.png'

                                # *****************---Footer---*****************

                                data["attachments"][0]["footer"] = str(
                                    data["attachments"][0]["footer"] + ' | ' + datetime.now().strftime(
                                        '%Y-%m-%d [%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + "]")

                                # -------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                a = get_value_identifier.split("%") #We split the identifier meaning it will be name image number
                                for i, items in zip(range(len(old_list)), old_list): #We split the length of old_list length and the old_list (I didn't think out of anything other way than this. This can be changed)
                                    old_list_value = old_list[i].split("%") #We also split the old_list values the same way as we did with *a =...*

                                    if a[0] in old_list_value[0]: #if the first value of both *a* in inside somewhere in a old_list first value.....

                                        if old_list_value[2] < a[2]: #We check if the number is higher than the old_list. If it is then we do the things below

                                            data["attachments"][0]["title"] = information['name'].upper()

                                            data_list.append((webhook_list[counters], data))

                                            for hook, data in data_list:
                                                threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(hook, data)).start()

                                            old_list[i] = get_value_identifier
                                            break

                                        elif len(old_list_value[2]) >= len(a[2]): #We check if the number is lower than the old_list. If it is then we do the things below

                                            old_list[i] = get_value_identifier
                                            break

                                else: #If nothing is found then we just do things below here and add the value to old_list.

                                    data["attachments"][0]["title"] = information['name'].upper()

                                    data_list.append((webhook_list[counters], data))

                                    for hook, data in data_list:
                                        threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(hook, data)).start()

                                    old_list.append(get_value_identifier)

            else:
                randomtime = random.randint(3, 7)
                logger.warn('No new item found! - retrying in %d secs' % (randomtime))
                time.sleep(randomtime)
```

As you can see, this is my code that I do for opening each json format and we use *data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())* meaning it will add up into "data" which is a json.

```
directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
      with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
      data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())
```

Whenever one of the loop is done - It adds up everything into data and later on at the end we can print out the data or send it through a requests to Discord/Slack.

But in the end before I want to print it out to discord/slack - I am checking first of all if the name is already in the list. We do that by splitting each % which will contains "Name image Number"

In the if statement we check if a[0] (Which is current thread found) - if it is somewhere in a old list.

- IF it is in the old list then we check the last number on the object
  if it is higher or lower
- IF it is higher then we print it out since its a increase of value
  and then we change the previous old_list value to this new one.
- IF it is lower then we just change the previous old_list value to the
  new one.
- IF there is none in the old_list that matches then we just append it
  to the list.

.

```
 a = get_value_identifier.split("%")
for i, items in zip(range(len(old_list)), old_list):
   old_list_value = old_list[i].split("%")

   if a[0] in old_list_value[0]:

      if old_list_value[2] < a[2]:

        data["attachments"][0]["title"] = information['name'].upper()

        data_list.append((webhook_list[counters], data))

        for hook, data in data_list:
            threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(hook, data)).start()

        old_list[i] = get_value_identifier
        break

      elif len(old_list_value[2]) > len(a[2]):

         old_list[i] = get_value_identifier
         break

   else:

     data["attachments"][0]["title"] = information['name'].upper()

     data_list.append((webhook_list[counters], data))

     for hook, data in data_list:
        threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(hook, data)).start()

     old_list.append(get_value_identifier)
```

and here is the mechanic issue.

The issue I am having is that at the beginning when we run

```
  directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
    for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
          with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
          data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())
```

is that it will be looping through the function above

```
 a = get_value_identifier.split("%")
 for i, items in zip(range(len(old_list)), old_list):
     old_list_value = old_list[i].split("%")......
```

x times depending on how many files there is in the slack. This will be a issue after second loop becuase if the first loop find a new item. It will add it into the old_list using append but that means when the second loop with slack/discord it means that there will be a value in the old_list that contains it. And here is where it start continuing... Meaning the first loop will always be correct but after that it will give you not the correct answers.

My question in that case is two question

1. How can I make so whenever the first loop hits etc if statement or elif or else. It should print the same for all discord/slack at once .
2. If it hits if or elif statement. Inside those I have that it should take the value from old_list[i] and change that value to the "newer" one which is get_value_identifier. How can I make it so it does it only once. Because I believe if I run through 3 slacks in my case. It will be 3 same values in the old_list due to the for loop.

I think that is it for me and I hope I explained so good I could! Please. If there is any more question to be added or anything. I will be pretty active now and I will be able to edit to either upgrade the question due to your questions below!

Comment: I read your post but it's not clear what you want to do. I suggest you rewrite the beginning, making it clear what you want to do. At the rewrite, also try removing fill words like "basically" to make your sentences shorter. At the end you refer to "the first loop" - it would be helpful if you added comments to the code so it's quicker to find what you talk about

Comment: @576i Alright I will do that right away

Comment: @576i There we go! I think its quite better now. - Im adding also the comments for coding now